# How do I make certain packages not hoist in pnpm workspace

Tags: pnpm, pnpm-workspace

Hi Im using a pnpm workspace.
I have 1 project where I don't want the node_modules folder symlinked. I need to be able to upload this directly along with its deps to another service.

I tried creating a `.npmrc` file in the project directory with the following contents.

```
hoist=false
symlink=false
node-linker=hoisted
```

But I tried running `pnpm i` but I still see that some packages are still being symlinked.

Is there anything else I need to add?